# Adding "delete" button in mat-select

Tags: angular, angular-material

Hello Stackoverflow community,

I am trying to add a "Delete" button next to each *mat-option* of a given *mat-select* when hovering over the option itself. The hover portion works just fine. However, given the way I implemented this button, the data displayed after selecting an option is altered :

**From this :**

[image]

**To this :**

[image]

Here is a snippet of the code used :

**HTML template :**

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-select>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let year of data" [value]="year">

      <div style="display:flex; justify-content: space-between">
        <span>{{year}}</span>
        <span></span>
        <span class="deleteYear" (click)="openDeleteDialog(year)">
          <i class="material-icons-outlined">clear</i>
        </span>
      </div>

    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

I believe there is no relevant code in the typescript component to share. However, I'm more than willing to provide the source code if needed.

**2 Questions :**

1. How can I get rid of the "clear" (name of the "X" icon) text appended to the desired "year" string?
2. Right now, when I click the "X" button, the functions fires just fine. However, it also selects that option in the mat-select as by clicking on the "X" I also click on the row. Is there any way I can have the function fire but make the form not to believe that I selected the row?

Thanks to all for your support,

Answer (score 3):

You can use [mat-select-tigger](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#customizing-the-trigger-label) So, your .html becomes like

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-select [formControl]="value">
    <mat-select-trigger>
      {{value.value}}
       <span class="deleteYear" (click)="delete($event,value.value)">
          <mat-icon>clear</mat-icon>
        </span>
    </mat-select-trigger>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let year of data" [value]="year">

      <div style="display:flex; justify-content: space-between">
        <span>{{year}}</span>
        <span></span>
        <span class="deleteYear" (click)="delete($event,year)">
          <mat-icon>clear</mat-icon>
        </span>
      </div>

    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

And your function delete (*)

```
  value=new FormControl()

  delete(event:any,year:any)
  {
    event.preventDefault(); //<--prevent default
    event.stopPropagation();  //stop propagation
    this.data=this.data.filter(x=>x!=year) //<--remove the element from data
    if (this.value.value==year)
        this.value.setValue(null) //<--if the value is the remove data, set null

  }
```

the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tg25jp?file=src/app/select-custom-trigger-example.ts)

(*) I use a formControl, if you has a formGroup change this.value by

```
this.form.get(value)
```

Comment: Took a little bit of fine-tuning but put me on the right track. I believe everything in the `<span>` tag in the `<mat-select-trigger>` isn't necessary. That's what's actually displaying the "X" after selecting a desired option. If you agree, please edit the answer so I can mark it as the accepted answer for future users stumbling across this question. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with instead of using "i" tag for icon

```
<mat-icon>clear</mat-icon>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I indeed tried using the MatIcon module but the result is the same. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It works with `mat-select-trigger`

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <mat-select [formControl]="value">
        <mat-select-trigger>
          {{value.value}}
        </mat-select-trigger>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let year of data" [value]="year">
    
          <div style="display:flex; justify-content: space-between">
            <span>{{year}}</span>
            <span></span>
            <span class="deleteYear" (click)="delete($event,year)">
              <mat-icon>clear</mat-icon>
            </span>
          </div>
    
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```